# Jquery ajax sort Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a little problem sorting JSON.

So here is my JSON data:

```
[
    {
        nom: "TERRES LATINES",
        numero: "0473343687",
        image: "http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/api/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/IMG_1165.jpg",
        timedate: "30/6/2017 - 7:5:45"
    },
    {
        nom: "TERRES LATINES",
        numero: "0473343687",
        image: "http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/api/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/IMG_1165.jpg",
        timedate: "30/6/2017 - 7:5:45"
    },
    {
        nom: "LE FURCO",
        numero: "0473156551",
        image: "http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/api/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/IMG_0843.jpg",
        timedate: "30/6/2017 - 18:4:6"
    },
    {
        nom: "A L&rsquo;IDEE",
        numero: "0473193488",
        image: "http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/api/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/IMG_0299.jpg",
        timedate: "30/6/2017 - 23:5:56"
    }
]
```

With this Ajax jQuery code I can call all the entries in a table:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/app/text.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        data.forEach(function(post) {
            $( '#contenttableau' ).append( '<tr><td>' + post.nom + '</td><td>' + post.numero + '</td><td>' + post.timedate + '</td><td></td></tr>' );
        });
    }
});
```

How can I get the number of time TERRES LATINES is present like in the following?

- TERRES LATINES 2
- LE FURCO 1
- A L'IDEE 1

Comment: do you have it in sorted order

Comment: I can sort all the entries with jQuery Tablesorter

Comment: So you just want to add another cell with the number of times each key is present etc.

Comment: i means your json data is sorted by nom

Comment: Adeneo that is correct

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like:

```
let counts = {}

data.forEach(function(obj) {
    counts[obj.nom] = (counts[obj.nom] || 0) + 1
})

let output = []

for(let nom in counts) {
    output.push([nom,counts[nom]].join(' '))
}

document.querySelector('output').innerHTML = ['<ul>', '<li>', output.join('</li><li>'), '</li>', '</ul>'].join('')
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/e33tkwrc/1/

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed

Answer (score -1):

Create a map that holds the count for each key, and append it with the other values, something like

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "GET",
    url      : 'http://s604712774.onlinehome.fr/bonapp/app/text.json',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(data) {

        var map = {};

        data.forEach(function(post) {
            var key = post.numero;

            if ( key in map ) {
                map[key]++;
            } else {
                map[key] = 1;
            }
        });

        data.forEach(function(post) {
            var td1 = $('<td />', {html : post.nom}),
                td2 = $('<td />', {html : post.numero}), 
                td3 = $('<td />', {html : post.timedate}),
                td4 = $('<td />', {html : map[post.numero]}),
                tr  = $('<tr />');

            $( '#contenttableau' ).append( tr.append(td1, td2, td3, td4) );
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L4gjfnks/1/)